# how to patch config map in openshift cluster to add the root.pem cert in the existing configmap. Goal is to add the cert in existing cm

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

how to patch config map in openshift cluster to add the root.pem cert in the existing configmap. Goal is to add the cert in existing cm in below format
apiVersion: v1
data:
ca-bundle.crt: |
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

new cert is saved in the file.

oc patch command but didnt work,
i can add manually using edit, but want to automate so need to learn the use of patch command in openshift

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.